Christian Antichrist and Mahdi
People claim that the Islamic Mahdi will be the Christian Antichrist due to similarities such as ruling for 7 years and riding on a white horse.There are also similarities between the Islamic dajjal and Jesus (Isa) as dajjal will heal the sick and perform miracles and claim to be the Messiah to the Jews.
Can anyone tell me if these claims are wrong?

I’m voting to close this question because it does not belong on this site.

"People claim that …" — Which people? What exactly did they say? A good question will provide explicit quotations and citations for such claims. A papal encyclical for example would present quite a different question than a tract from a church with only three members. ¶ "the islamic dajjal" — an explanation should accompany this term; why would readers of a site about Christianity be expected to understand what it means?

People make all sorts of claims, like the world is flat, or the moon is made of blue cheese. Those claims are not true.  But are you asking if it is true that people claim the Mahdi will be the Christian antichrist, or are you asking if it is true that the Mahdi will be the Christian antichrist?  It is true that claims are being made, but are those claims true - from a Christian perspective.

My understanding is limited here, but it really sounds like a question for the Islam stack exchange? Can we migrate this over there maybe?

The people who make these claims are Muslims.  Here is a simple overview:

According to Islamic prophecy, the Mahdi’s return will be preceded by a number of events during three years of horrendous world chaos, and he will rule over the Arabs and the world for seven years. His appearance will be accompanied by two resurrections, one of the wicked and one of the righteous. According to Shiite teachings, Jesus will accept the Mahdi’s leadership, and the two great branches of Abraham’s family will be reunited forever.

This article explains:

The phrase Al-Masih ad-Dajjal literally means “the fraudulent Jesus” or “the lying Messiah.” Often referred to simply as Dajjal, this character is the Muslim equivalent to the Antichrist in Christian eschatology. According to Islamic beliefs concerning the end times, Dajjal will fool all the world’s people, except for true Muslims, through miracles and other signs. Eventually, he will be killed when the true Jesus—known in Islam as Isa—returns to earth.  Once on the scene, this false savior will fool people with miraculous powers, and he will conquer the entire world except for the Islamic holy cities of Medina and Mecca.


Muslims generally believe in the appearance of yet another end-times figure, known as the Mahdi, meaning “guided one.” This man will be the perfect Muslim and the leader of the worldwide Islamic people. He will defeat Al-Masih ad-Dajjal in cooperation with Isa (Jesus), who will return to earth. Isa will kill Dajjal with a spear and unite the world under the banner of “true” Islam. Sunni Muslims differ as to whether Isa and the Mahdi are separate figures. Shia Islam primarily identifies this Mahdi as “the last Imam,” a figure who has been on earth—in hiding—for many centuries. Ahmadiyya Muslims believe the Mahdi was their founder, Ghulam Ahmad.

This article delves into the Shia view:

The Twelfth Imam is not a Christian/biblical idea, but rather a concept in Shia Islam tied to Muslim beliefs about the end times. Shia Islam is the second-largest denomination of Muslims; it gives greater weight to the title Imam than does Sunni Islam. Most Shia believe there have only been twelve “true” Imams, the last of which has been hiding unseen on earth since the ninth century. According to this belief, “the last Imam” will one day return, along with Jesus Christ, to defeat Satan and an antichrist-like figure, Al-Masih ad-Dajjal.

According to Revelation 6:2 and Daniel 9:27, the Antichrist will pose as a man of peace, ready to set the world right. It is easy to see how the Antichrist, promising a false peace, could be welcomed by a world hungry for a ceasefire and security. Some may see him as the Mahdi, and others may see him as the Messiah. In fact, Jesus warned that the Antichrist would mimic the true Messiah and be accepted by those who rejected Christ (John 5:43).
Christians need to heed the words of 1 John 4:1–4, “Dear friends, do not believe every spirit, but test the spirits to see whether they are from God, because many false prophets have gone out into the world. This is how you can recognize the Spirit of God: Every spirit that acknowledges that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh is from God, but every spirit that does not acknowledge Jesus is not from God. This is the spirit of the antichrist, which you have heard is coming and even now is already in the world. You, dear children, are from God and have overcome them, because the one who is in you is greater than the one who is in the world.”

Joel Richardson's book   Will Islam Be Our Future?: A Study of Biblical and Islamic Eschatology and The Islamic Antichrist will be helpful for details.
However, I don't see good reasons to think Islamic Dajjal to be representating the Biblical Christ. Because it's merely a warning against false Messiah, exactly the way Messiah warned his people in the end times in the NT. I also reject the contemporary Evangelical predictions of the antichrist to be the Saudi King Salman, as these are mere personal interpretations coming from a peculiar American end times doctrine.
Injil of Matthew 24:24

For false christs and false prophets will arise and perform great signs and wonders, so as to lead astray, if possible, even the elect.

The interesting comparison from the Dajjal account is actually between Christ and Allah, as it describes Dajjal to be an impersonator of the Lord (Rabb). Christ has been described in such accounts as a universal Saviour. The counterpart of the Dajjal is the true Messiah, and he's called Lord in Sahih al Bukhari 7408, etc.

Narrated Anas:The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah did not send any prophet but that he warned his nation of the one-eyed liar (Ad-Dajjal). He is one-eyed while your Lord is not one-eyed, The word 'Kafir' (unbeliever) is written between his two eyes."

The figure of the Islamic Mahdi seems closer to the second coming of Christ due to his establishing peace and justice, though it seems to have been a bifurcated version of Jesus. It should be noted that the concept of Mahdi is not well attested in the authentic Islamic sources of Sunni Islam, it is only mentioned in the Hadith and among the Shia's sources, thus, it could well be a later Islamic version of the Christian or Jewish doctrines of the Messiah.
As noted by a reddit answer: Throughout Islamic history and scholarship, there have been notable figures among them that rejected the belief of a Mahdi among them being the historian Ibn Khaldun, early Sunni Hasan Al-Basri who said that Jesus would fulfill the role of the Mahdi, along with modern scholars such as Yusuf Al-Qaradawi and Chief Qatari Judge Abdullah bin Zaid Al-Mahmood
